# How to pass the button value in ajax url and display the json response in bootstrap panel body?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, laravel-5.4

**Laravel View code:**

```
<div class="container"  style="display:none;" id="panel1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="color:#0000FF" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Gateways!"> 
        <input type="button" value="Haghway Lite"  style="background-color:transparent;border:none;width:100%;height:100%;" name="button1" id="button1"><font size="5"></font>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" align="center">
        <img src="haghwaylitecontroller.jpg" width="100" height="100"> 
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This my view code.

**Script(ajax):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  $("#button1").click(function(){
      var button1 = $(this).val();
        if(button1) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('panelview').'/'}}"+button1,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {


                    $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                       $("#panel1").append('<div "'+ value.panel1 +'"></div>');
                 });
                //alert("success");
                }
            });
        }else{
             alert("failed");
        }
    });
});
```

In this script code, I calling the ajax function with the button id and trying to pass the value of button to be redirected to the mentioned url and the returned json response to be displayed on the panel body.  Here if I am trying to print the button value it alerts **NaN**

**Route:**

```
Route::get('panelview/{button1}','viewController@newProduct');
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function newProduct($button1)
 {

  $users=addModel::select('Desc')->where('Pname',$button1 )->first();;
  return json_encode($users);

 }
```

The controller code should fetches the correspoding record based on the value of button and return the response.

Comment: why dont you just pass the value `Haghway Lite` instead of +button

Comment: yes sir,the same.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No sir, the value differs for different buttons

Comment: It just pass on to the if condition but doesn't display the value fetched from db.  Instead of that it gave an alert meassage,inside the success function  that works!

Comment: It will be very helpful,if anyone knows about it.!!